# OpenCV HOG Gpu Implementation

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I tried to use the HOG GPU version provided by OpenCV 3.
But, I was surprised about the speed. 
It seems slowest than the CPU version.

This is my code:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::HOG> hog_cuda;
hog_cuda->setGammaCorrection(false);
hog_cuda->setNumLevels(13);
hog_cuda->setHitThreshold(1.4);
hog_cuda->setWinStride(cv::Size(8, 8));
hog_cuda->setScaleFactor(1.05);
hog_cuda->setGroupThreshold(8);
hog_cuda->setSVMDetector(hog_cuda->getDefaultPeopleDetector());
hog_cuda->detectMultiScale(cv::cuda::GpuMat(m_img), founds, 0);
```

Do you have any idea?

This is my card: 
Device 0:  "GeForce GT 750M"  2048Mb, sm_30, 384 cores, Driver/Runtime ver.7.50/7.50

My CPU: 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7 -QUADCORE 8 Threads

These are the performance:
GPU: 10/11 FPS
CPU: 17/18 FPS

Comment: Please add details about your hardware and the timings that you get for both runs.

Comment: Device 0:  "GeForce GT 750M"  2048Mb, sm_30, 384 cores, Driver/Runtime ver.7.50/7.50 - GPU FPS: 10/11 FPS CPU FPS: 17/18 FPS

Comment: It's quite probable that the  overhead simply makes GPU usage redundant in this case.

Comment: Can you better explain?

Comment: I mean when you use GPU version, you copy the data on the memory into GPU's memory. This creates an additional computation. Therefore, if your calculation on GPU is not much different than CPU, the overhead might cause GPU version to be slower.